# Is Wolfram Alpha wrong with a simple derivative?

Tags: partial-derivative, wolfram-alpha

Let $f=\frac{x^2w(y-z)t}{18l}$

then (imho):

$\frac{\partial{f(x,y,z)}}{\partial{w}}=\frac{x^2t(y-z)}{18l}$

However Wolfram Alpha produces a quite different result:

Wolfram alpha result
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d[%28x^2w%28y-z%29t%29%2F%2818l%29%2Cw]

So who's wrong this time - me or the computer? If the latter, then why?

Comment: Just add a `*` to tell wolfram you want multiplication, not application ... and everything works as expected: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d[%28x^2w*%28y-z%29t%29%2F%2818l%29%2Cw]

Comment: Yeah, I meant it with respect to w, sorry for that typo. Already corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Wolfram is interpreting "$w(y-z)$" as a *function* of $y-z$, which clearly contains only y and z as variables. Try enclosing "$w$" in parentheses: $D[\frac{(x^2(w)(y-z)t)}{(18l)},w].$ It should work.

Comment: This is correct, distributing $w(y-z)$ to $wy-wz$ also works

Answer (score 1):

If you do $$\mathrm{D}\left[\frac{x^{2}w(y-z)t}{18l},w\right]$$ instead you will get the expected answer. Perhaps it doesn't parse "${2}w$" the way we might expect.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant taking the derivative with respect to $w$.

You are right, obviously, and Alpha is wrong. As for why... who knows? Submit a ticket with Wolfram. If you put in explicit multiplications, it works: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d[%28x^2*w*%28y-z%29*t%29%2F%2818*l%29%2Cw]

Answer (score 0):

When people set variables for programming, the variables are giving declarations of more than a letter many times so it is discriptive. For this reason, wolfram will read a concatenation of variables as one variable not two unless specified by parenthesis or multiplication.

If we had a times b times c, we couldn't enter abc since that will be treated as one variable not three.